# Marshmallow serialization - a way to catch exceptions on a per field basis?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, marshmallow

Is there a way to catch exceptions (that occur when accessing a property) on a per-field basis with marshmallow [1] ?

I want to use marshmallow to serialize documents of a mongo db (mongoengine) database.
With nested schemas, referenced objects are serialized as well.

However, in case of a reference that does not exist, mongoengine throws an error. I would like to catch that error in the process of serialization ( e.g and set field null)

[1] *library for converting complex datatypes, such as objects, to and from native Python datatypes* https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/api_reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up subclassing the `Nested` field and overriding the `get_value` method.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from mongoengine.errors import DoesNotExist


class SafeNested(fields.Nested):
    def get_value(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().get_value(*args, **kwargs)
        except DoesNotExist:
            return {}
```